# DataTable RowExpansion Lazy Load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am currently trying to implement a lazy loading row expansion.
I added a dataGrid in my rowExpansion which value attribute is a method which gets a detailed User from database.

When I debugged this method `(userBacking.getDetailedUserById(Long userId))` I recognized that this method is called minimum 5 times when I click on a row.
Does anyone know why this method is called so many times?
Are there better approaches to implement a lazy loading row Expansion?

```
<p:dataTable id="myPassengerTable"
                    value="#{userBacking.userTableData}" var="user"
                    selection="#{myRoutesBacking.selectedUser}"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    emptyMessage="no users">

                    <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{userBacking.onRowSelect}" />

                    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect"
                        listener="#{userBacking.onRowUnselect}" />

                    <p:column styleClass="expand#{user.id}"
                        style="display:none;">
                        <p:rowToggler />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column >
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{user.username}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:rowExpansion>
                        <p:dataGrid var="detailedUser"
                            value="#{userBacking.getDetailedUserById(user.Id)}"
                            columns="1" rows="1">
                            <p:panelGrid>
                                <p:row>
                                    <p:column>#{detailedUser.firstName} #{detailedUser.lastName}</p:column>
                                </p:row>
                            </p:panelGrid>
                        </p:dataGrid>
                    </p:rowExpansion>
                </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: The reason is well explained here (and also the workaround: never implement heavy operations in getters) http://stackoverflow.com/a/2090062/870122

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (PrimeFaces 6+) `p:rowToggler` uses Ajax loading, so it's lazy by default. After reading [p:rowExpansion gets rendered even though it's not toggled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943472/prowexpansion-gets-rendered-even-though-its-not-toggled), it seems that this wasn't always the case (up to PrimeFaces 5). So, if possible, just upgrade.

And for the multiple getter calls you should, as already pointed out, check: [Why JSF calls getters multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times).